# TimeoutException while executing stored procedure from UI in .NET Core 2.2

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a requirement to execute a stored procedure after an awaitable operation. I am currently executing the stored procedure using EF `_dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand`.

I wrote the functionality in a Web API solution. When I am invoking the Web API from POSTMAN, it is successfully executing the procedure with no issues.

But when I tried executing the procedure from my UI interface, it is throwing a "timeout exception".

```
public async void ProcessEmployeeDetailsAsync(XmlDocument xmlContent)
{
    // Some Business logic

    if (_dbContext.Entry(EmployeeBatch).State == EntityState.Modified)
    {
        var recordCount = await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

        if (recordCount > 0)
        {
             SqlParameter EmpBatchId = new SqlParameter("@IPV_EmployeeBatchId", batchId);
             _dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
                                    "exec uspEmployeeBatchValidation_BatchId @IPV_BatchId",
                                    EmpBatchId);  // TimeOutException occuring
         }
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
services.AddDbContextPool<EmployeeContext>((serviceProvider, optionBuilder) =>
            {
                optionBuilder
                    .UseLazyLoadingProxies()
                    .UseSqlServer(_Configuration.GetConnectionString("EmployeeContext"));
            });
```

Can anyone please help me where I am missing? As I am new to asynchronous programming.

Comment: What's the error message _exactly_.  You may need to:  Turn on Query Store https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/best-practice-with-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver15  and/or examine the performance DMVs like session wait stats https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-session-wait-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15  the running requests https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-requests-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: A timeout means "You're taking too long and I am not waiting anymore". That means that SQL isn't returning the results in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: You can try running the same stored procedure with the same `batchId` directly in SQL Management Studio and see how long it takes for it to complete.

Comment: First, make sure you look at the inner exceptions (if there are some, and go as deep as possible.) and see if you get a different or more descriptive error message.

Second, how long does it take to get a result in Postman? I see below your command timeout is 60 seconds, so I assume it should return in less time than that but wanted to point it out. Based on your other comments it sounds like CommandTimeout vs ConnectionTimeout is not an issue but again wanted to bring it up in case it helps you or someone else reading this.

Comment: I checked twice the exception - It says "Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
The statement has been terminated." But when I make the same request from POSTMAN, it works fine. I really don't understand where I'm missing.